# Can I add a second dishwasher to an existing power circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, dishwasher

Our current dishwasher has a dedicated 120v 20A circuit breaker (KY, USA). We are thinking of adding a second one. We will likely be alternating the use of the dishwashers but may use both concurrently (after parties, etc.). Should I wire a second dedicated circuit from the breaker (a job as it's a finished house) or can I get away with the existing circuit?

Thank you,
David

Comment: Where in the world are you? While I believe the answer will probably be "no" you can't add the new dishwasher to the existing circuit, local codes may vary, so knowing a locale will be helpful

Comment: Clarified the question. I am in KY, USA.

Comment: Check the power specs on the dishwasher you have and the one you're thinking of adding. If they add up to less than 80% of 20A (16A) you should be able to run them at the same time without tripping the breaker. If more, you definitely risk breaker trips while using both. Not sure what code says about sharing one circuit for multiple dishwashers, though.

Comment: @nobody I don't see any requirement in NEC 422 or 210.23 that limits two non-continuous (less than 3 hours at full current) appliances to less than 100% as long as no additional receptacles are supplied unless the installation instructions with either appliance has restrictions. Code requires following instructions since they are part off Listing.

Answer (score 2):

David!  We have 2 DW in our kitchen and I ran a dedicated circuit for each to be safe. Also, that extra capacity might come in handy for an instant hot or garbage disposal.  Code is getting stricter and stricter on hard wired appliances...what you can share with plug attached appliances, etc. It gets ambiguous at times. IE: if my DW has a cord, is that a plug attached device?

Since you are doing a major kitchen remodel including running a new cable for the new range, I'd strongly suggest running another 20 amp circuit for the 2nd DW.

BTW.  Good job asking specific questions.

Comment: Thank you sir, you have been very helpful!  I agree, once the wall is open, might as well run a wirე, just wanted to make sure whether it was necessary - by my estimate it was and thanks for confirming.

Comment: @David  Thanks for the communication. BTW, I edited your edit, you said 100volts and I edited it to say 120...just a typo on your part.  FYI. +

Comment: Yes! I definitely meant 120v, though I have seen 60-80 volts in the past during bad brown-outs where my UPS was gasping for power :D

Comment: Another idea. Our garbage disposal has a dedicated 15A circuit (14/2 wire).

New dishwasher calls for "15 A or 20 A, fused supply" "A maximum of 2 field wiring supply conductors (12 AWG largest size) plus 1 grounding in the terminal box".

Can I just move the garbage disposal to the existing 20A dishwasher circuit and use the freed-up 15A circuit for the #2 dishwasher? Thanks. I want to make these circuits 100% safe and functional but rather not do extra wiring unless I absolutely have to.

Comment: I'm going to have to give you a "maybe" answer. Will it functionally work? Yes in most cases, unless you get a monster garbage disposal and the DW is in it's dry (heating) part of it's cycle. According to previous codes yes, I think even up to 2017 NEC.  I'd check with the AHJ to ask that question.  It will probably work, but may or may not pass inspection or be code compliant...depends upon the AHJ and what code they are enforcing.  But if this isn't being inspected....well..... then.

Comment: Oh, just remembered, since the microwave circuit is also being freed up, I could also use that 20A circuit. Just need to put a junction there and run it to the different part of kitchen, possibly under the floor (yes, the floor will be ripped up for new tile as well)

Comment: @David  Sounds like you're working thru it all and have good options. Just remember any junctions/connections must be permanently accessible.

Comment: Thanks for that last tip. I will likely put it on the inside back of the kitchen cabinet and put a blank cover plate on it. I hope that's all I need for that. Yes, it really helps to bounce off ideas. you have been so helpful, George, thank you again.

Comment: Your disposal is a motor load, your circuit capacity needs to be calculated at 125%.

Comment: Oh, and by the way if using a receptacle for the dishwasher the code now requires it in the adjacent cabinet.